# Konjunktiv in "Wer sich etwas wünscht, müsste ..."

Tags: usage, subjunctive, modal-verb

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> ..., aber es fällt auf, dass die Generation Merkel im Spiegel der Umfragen zu großen Teilen eine Haltung zeigt, die mit Merkels Politikstil korrespondiert. In gewollt unpolitischen Zeiten wächst eine vergleichsweise unpolitische Generation heran, die sich das Projekt der aufregungslosen Wohlstandsmehrung offenbar zu eigen gemacht hat. **Wer sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, müsste eher die Bundeskanzlerin kritisieren als die Jugend.** Politisch sind sie Kinder der Stille.

Warum wird hier der Konjunktiv **müsste** verwendet? Es scheint mir als eine normale Aussage, wie

> (a) Wer sich ein Haus wünscht, **muss** Geld sparen.

Ich fasse kein Bedürfnis des Konjunktivs. Oder sollte es wie Folgendes heißen?

> (b) Wer sich ein Haus wünscht, **müsste** Geld sparen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Autor nimmt nicht an (kann nicht annehmen!), dass jemand, "der sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht", in jedem Fall auch Kritik an der Bundeskanzlerin oder an der Jugend üben wird. Er will zum Ausdruck bringen, an wen die Kritik gerichtet sein müsste, *wenn* sie denn geäußert wird, aber er weiß nicht, *ob* sie geäußert wird. Deshalb der Konjunktiv. Man kann sich einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz denken:

> Wer sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, müsste - wenn er aus diesem Wunsch heraus eine Kritik äußern will - eher die Bundeskanzlerin kritisieren als die Jugend.

Es wäre aber auch der Indikativ möglich, im Sinne von "Wer A sagt, muss auch B sagen." Da der Satz dann aber den Charakter eines Appells oder zumindest einer Voraussetzung-Konsequenz-Beziehung bekäme, würde man im Interesse einer klaren Aussage aber auf den Vergleich von Bundeskanzlerin und Jugend eher verzichten und direkt schreiben:

> Wer sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, muss die Bundeskanzlerin kritisieren.

In ähnlicher Weise funktionieren Deine beiden anderen Beispiele. Beide Varianten sind möglich

> (a) Wer sich ein Haus wünscht, muss Geld sparen. (Sonst wird das nichts mit dem Haus.)
>   (b) Wer sich ein Haus wünscht, müsste Geld sparen (wenn er denn den Wunsch tatsächlich in die Tat umsetzen wollte).

Answer (score 5):

Der Grund für den Irrealis ist, dass es keinen Grund zu der Annahme gibt, dass jemand, der sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, überhaupt jemanden kritisieren möchte. Es wird gewissermaßen die hypothetische Situation behandelt, dass jemand sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht und deswegen jemanden kritisieren möchte. Über diesen hypothetischen Fall sagt der Autor dann, dass derjenige eher Merkel kritisieren müsse als die Jugend. Es ist hier also eine implizite irreale Bedingung versteckt:

> Wer sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, müsste, **wenn er denn schon diesen Wunsch durch Kritik in die Tat umsetzen wollte**, eher die Bundeskanzlerin kritisieren als die Jugend.

Dies ist im vorliegenden Fall insbesondere wichtig, da es ansonsten als direkter Aufruf zur Kritik verstanden werden könnte:

> Wer sich eine politischere Jugend wünscht, muss die Bundeskanzlerin kritisieren.

Da der Wunsch nach einer politischeren Jugend allgegenwärtig ist, würde der Autor bei der obigen Formulierung jeden dazu aufrufen, die Bundeskanzlerin zu deswegen zu kritisieren. Das möchte er nicht unbedingt und es wäre außerdem ein starkes Abweichen von der journalistischen Neutralität.

Answer (score 1):

Der Konjunktiv kann hier schon angebracht sein, und zwar weil eben niemand die Bundeskanzlerin (für ihre mangelhafte Jugendarbeit?) kritisiert, sondern die Jugend wegen ihres politischen Desinteresses kritisiert wird. Ohne Konjunktiv geht das zwar auch, in dieser Form bringt aber der Schreiber deutlicher zum Ausdruck, dass er es für unwahrscheinlich hält, dass jemand die Kanzlerin kritisieren wird.